# (WPF) How can i fill an Expander-Controltemplate with content?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, expander, contentpresenter

I'm t trying to create an custom Expander with a Controltemplate. My first question is: Where can I put the content of the Expander (not the text shown on the Expander, the content which turnsd visible if you click the Expander)?

This is my Code in App.xaml:

```
    <Application.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="FileExpanderButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Image Name="BrowseUsedFiles" Source="F:\AudioNodeGUI_XAML\images\Browse_used_files.jpg">

            </Image>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="FileExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <DockPanel>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" Template="{StaticResource FileExpanderButton}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
            </DockPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ExpanderContent" 

              Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And another question: What exactly does the ContentPresenter? Can I replace it simply with my Content?

Comment: It is the ContentPresenter that presents the content. It should work if you set the IsExpanded property of the Expander to true.

Comment: So with the ContentPresenter but without the Templatebinding I can in the main.xaml file just type :     <Expander name="testExpander"...>  <Button name="contentTest " .../> </Expander>

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. But yes, you need to create an Expander that uses your custom Style.

Answer (score 0):

`Expander` is a `ContentControl`, meaning it contains content (other XAML), but that content is not defined in the control template, it is defined by whoever is using the control.

`ContentPresenter` is used inside the control template to display that content, just like you appear to be doing.